# How do I convert an octal number to decimal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, octal

I am trying to find a clean way of referencing an array's index using octal numbering. If I am looking for the array index that is octal 13 it should return the value for `a[11]`.

This is what I have come up with to accomplish it, but it doesn't seem very elegant or efficient:

```
a = [ 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62 ]

v = 13

puts a[v.to_s.to_i(8)]  # => 61
 # OR
puts a[v.to_s.oct]      # => 61
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: The fact that you need to access array with that number means nothing at all.  So, I discarded all mentions of array from tags and caption.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't sure if there was possibly something unique about the index of an array that I could access. This is very new territory for me! Thank you for correcting my error.

Comment: the thing is that I think it's obvious that there is no programming language, where it would matter :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Ruby's octal integer literal syntax. Place a 0 before your number, and Ruby will convert it to octal while parsing:

```
v = 013 # => 11
a[v]    # => 61
```

If the octal number is coming from an outside source like a file, then it is already a string and you'll have to convert it just like you did in your example:

```
number = gets.chomp # => "13"
v = number.to_i(8)  # => 11
a[v]                # => 61
```

Comment: Sweet! That's what I'm talking about! Thanks.

Comment: a total gotcha for SSNs and other situations that can begin with a zero. :)