# ruby basic data type conversion

Tags: ruby, types

I got some weired problem while converting data type in ruby.

Here are some of the outputs that i got in console

```
0123 and enter gave me output 83
12345600.to_s   #=> "12345600"
```

but

```
012345600.to_s gave me #=> "2739072" but i expect "012345600"
```

Seems like when there is 0 at the beginning of number the output is not as expected.

Can any one explain why this is happening? or provide me a solution so that i can get my expected output.

Thanks

Comment: You should have tried `08` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a 0 at the start of a number makes the interpreter/compiler interpret the following digits as an octal number sequence (base 8) not a decimal number sequence (base 10). Therefore the number you entered is an octal number and not decimal.

You can test this on a scientific calculator by putting it into octal mode and then switching to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a number with a zero in Ruby is telling the parser that you are going to write the number in octal notation. Heres another SO with some info:

[How do I convert an octal number to decimal in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509106/how-do-i-convert-an-octal-number-to-decimal-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return zero, but you can do this.

```
0123.to_s(8)
#=> "123"
```

Actually I am interested in how did you get such numbers like 0123?

Answer (score 0):

"Numbers" like a phone number `02555555555` aren't numbers at all. They're merely strings that only contain digits in them.