# Different outputs by integer in Rails' console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, integer

I can't figure it out why, when I type `67` in  Rails' console, the output is `67`, but `067` returns `55`.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a number with a 0 denotes that the number is in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation.

When you type in 067, you're really saying "67 in octal notation" or "67<sub>8</sub> (67 base 8)". When Ruby outputs that number it converts it to decimal (base 10).

Since 67<sub>8</sub> == 55<sub>10</sub>, Ruby outputs 55.

Check out "[How do I convert an octal number to decimal in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509106/how-do-i-convert-an-octal-number-to-decimal-in-ruby/3509126#3509126)" that mentions the leading 0.

See "[Octal to decimal converter](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.htm)" for an octal calculator:

[image]